# Translate strings in xml file

Tags: xml, excel, translation

I have an XML file that I want to send out for translations.
this is the unique structure:

```
<Lang name="en-us">
        <Fields>
            <Item name="FirstName" label="First Name" tooltip="Please provide your {0}" error="{0} Is not valid"></Item>
            <Item name="LastName" label="Last Name" tooltip="Please provide your {0}" error="{0} Is not valid"></Item>
            <Item name="Address" label="Address" tooltip="Please provide your Address {0}" error="{0} Is not valid"></Item>
            <Item name="CountryShortName" label="Country" tooltip="Please select your {0}" error="you must select your {0}">
                <Data name="IL" value="Israel"></Data>
                <Data name="US" value="USA"></Data>
                <Data name="DE" value="Jermany"></Data>
            </Item>
        <Fields>
   <Langs>
```

I don't want to send the translation company this XML because they will charge me double.
Is there anyway that I can somehow convert it to excel, send it and then reconvert to XML?
(the string are located in Atrributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel has functionality for mapping to and from xml files.

You can start from here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/map-and-unmap-xml-elements-HP010206397.aspx, and I'm sure there will be more online about setting this up

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't support to have lists of lists.

Comment: You sort of can: you end up with one row per (in your case) data element, with the item details repeated for each data line. Bear in mind that Excel is a "flat" structure and you're slotting "relational-ish" data into it. Otherwise you can use two maps from the same file and populate two sheets, one for data and one for Items, with just some header stuff from item on the data sheet for FK referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSLT to convert the xml to CSV file and then have a script to convert the CSV to XML.
I have used XSLT to convert XML to CSV but not the reverse.